# Stage3D iOS Antialiasing

Tags: flash, air, 3d, antialiasing, stage3d

Can someone confirm if it's possible to get anti-aliasing to work in a AIR for iOS project displaying stage3D content?
I did not get it to work, neither the debug-simulator nor on the device anti-aliasing is performed.
If it's possible, are there any further settings necessary other than passing the appropriate antialias value in context3D.configureBackBuffer()?

Answer (score 0):

For Stage3D on mobile, anti-aliasing is always off no matter what you set the property to.

Comment: Do you have any info on why this is so? (sure, anti-aliasing is expensive, but openGL ES 2.0 devices should be capable of doing it)

Answer (score 0):

As for today Stage3D anti-aliasing of 3D-content is still disabled for all mobile devices. This means that the edges of your 3D-objects will always be jagged on a mobile device. On HiDPI devices (e.g. Retina Display) the jaggedness is less obvious, but still clearly visible. And no, you currently can't make this better, i.e. "supersharp".

If you like the idea of AIR being able to deliver anti-aliasied 3D-content on mobile, there is a new feature-request on Adobe Bugbase concerning Stage3D anti-aliasing on mobile devices I would strongly encourage you to vote for:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4101164

Thank you & good luck with your 3D mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update with the most recent information (2017):

- On Desktop, Anti-Aliasing is always available in Stage3D, except if you run in Software mode.
- On Mobile, AIR 22 brought support for anti-aliasing in the "setRenderToTexture" API ([AIR 22 Release Notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_22_air_22_release_notes.html)).
- On iOS, you can activate anti-aliasing on the back buffer since AIR 24 ([AIR 24 Release Notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_24_air_24_release_notes.html)).

If you are a Starling developer, you can work around the current limitation on Android very easily. To render an object with anti-aliasing, simply attach a fragment filter with anti-aliasing enabled.

```
object.filter = new FragmentFilter();
object.filter.antiAliasing = 4;
```

To filter the complete screen, simply attach the filter to your root object.